# Paperclip : wrong bucket being used from yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

This has worked before, or so I believe.

For some reason, in my development environment, and even staging, Paperclip is using my production bucket instead of the development bucket.

Here is the part of the user model that relates to it

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    s3_permissions: :private,
                    path: "/:style/:id/:filename",
                    s3_protocol: "https",
                    styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#", icon: "26x26#" },
                    default_url: ":style/ico_missing_user.png"
```

And here, my yml file:

```
common: &common
  access_key_id: <%= ENV['S3_KEY'] %>
  secret_access_key: <%= ENV['S3_SECRET'] %>

development:
  <<: *common
  bucket: mydevbucket

staging:
  <<: *common
  bucket: mystagingbucket

production:
  <<: *common
  bucket: myprodbucket
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added "load_config.rb" file to my initializers directory:

load_config.rb

```
S3_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{::Rails.root}/config/s3.yml")[Rails.env]
```

and started using S3_CONFIG instead of `"#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"`

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
                    storage: :s3,
                    s3_credentials: S3_CONFIG,
                    s3_permissions: :private,
                    path: "/:style/:id/:filename",
                    s3_protocol: "https",
                    styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#", icon: "26x26#" },
                    default_url: ":style/ico_missing_user.png"
```

The solution above worked fine to set the bucket, but then I started having a problem with paperclip when uploading files, saying ECONN:Aborted.

The following is what i have understood to work :

```
  has_attached_file :avatar,
                    storage: :s3,
                    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml",
                    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET'],
                    s3_permissions: :private,
                    path: "/:style/:id/:filename",
                    s3_protocol: "https",
                    styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "100x100#", icon: "26x26#" },
                    default_url: ":style/ico_missing_user.png"
```

Notice I separated the bucket from the credentials. I did this inspired on the [rdocs](http://rdoc.info/github/thoughtbot/paperclip/Paperclip/Storage/S3) for paperclip, and on the following [sample](https://github.com/XFinger/Rails-Paperclip-S3-tutorial-example)